# copy and pasting error

Tags: excel, vba

Is there something that could cause the selection and copying of a range to *include* hidden columns in only some documents?

This is the code for the most part:

```
Set rngAcData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(bottomMostRow, rightMostColumn))
rngAcData.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(".....").Select
Range("H2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Please note that this works for about 98% of similarly formatted documents. But in the same documents. It will repeatedly always include the hidden columns. I've been tried to do it manually and I get the same results. I've tried to append `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to the range object that leads to an error `run time error: 1004 database or table range is not valid.` on the following advanced filter command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is copy and paste a Range while excluding hidden cells, then you're very close! Try this:

```
Public Sub CopyVisibleCells()
    Dim rngAcData As Range
    Set rngAcData = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5))
    rngAcData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H2")
End Sub
```

It will take the Range `A1` to `E5` into consideration, copy the visible cells, then paste into `H2` of `Sheet2`. You can modify it to fit your specific needs.

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
Sub test()
    Set rngAcData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(bottomMostRow, rightMostColumn))
    'Set rngAcData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion  'can use this alternatively
    rngAcData.Copy Sheets(".....").Range("H2")  ' avoid using select in vba
   ' Selection.Copy  ' not needed
    'Sheets(".....").Select  ' not needed
   ' Range("H2").Select  ' not needed
   ' ActiveSheet.Paste  ' not needed
End Sub
```

Comment: this actually wasn't able to fix it but thank you so much for the revision. The code works much faster like that. i'm suspecting there might be some bug in the document where a certain format prohibits excluding the copying of hidden columns.